# Updating Contentful Entry List

Tags: python, contentful, contentful-management

Trying to update an entry list.
I'm able to update an entry.name field. However, not entirely sure how to go about the list part.

Currently I can get the current list of items, but when I append a new one and set the entry.list = new_list, nothing happens.

```
    prev_products = entry.products
    print(prev_products)

    new_products = prev_products.append(
                                {
                                    "sys": {
                                        "type": "Link",
                                        "linkType": "Entry",
                                        "id": '1HYANUnDBW7tyMA6jMlknH'
                                        }
                                }
                            )

    print(new_products)
```

new_products turns out to be None.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `prev_products.append()` without having to reference another object - `list.append()` and `dict["newKey"] = "newValue"` modify the object in place. Like so:

```
prev_products.append(
                                {
                                    "sys": {
                                        "type": "Link",
                                        "linkType": "Entry",
                                        "id": '1HYANUnDBW7tyMA6jMlknH'
                                        }
                                }
                            )
```

Are you storing a list, or a dictionary? Since you're not getting an error, I assume that prev_products returns a list. If you're interested in the new product only, you can find that by replacing `print(new_products)` with `print(prev_products[-1])`. If you're interested in the new list entirely, then just `print(prev_products)` after appending the new element.

Key-value pairs like the above stored in a list is technically valid, but I personally wouldn't want to build a list of strings like that explicitly. Assuming that `entry.products` has the same structure as what you're appending:

```
    prev_products = entry.products
    print(prev_products)

    product_dict=json.loads(prev_products)  # this puts the list of strings in to key:value form

    product_dict["newKey"] = dict() # this adds the new key to 
                                    # your dictionary at the root level so you can add more elements

    product_dict["newKey"]["sys"] = dict()
    product_dict["newKey"]["sys"]["type"]="Link" 
    product_dict["newKey"]["sys"]["linkType"]="Entry"
    product_dict["newKey"]["sys"]["id"]='1HYANUnDBW7tyMA6jMlknH'
    print(new_products)
```

Comment: I see. Yeah, I'm "updating" an existing record. So appending it to the prev_products and then setting entry.products = new_products would be the way to do it. Thanks!